# Measure data transfer time from cpu to gpu and from gpu to cpu

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, gpu, cpu

I have a question about measuring computation time of neural network on gpu, when I using tensorflow's sess.run() function, it will include the time of data transfer(HtoD, DtoH).
So, I want to know is there any way to reduce or measure time data transfer time from cpu to gpu and from gpu to cpu?

start_out = time.time()
for j in range(1000):
    sess.run(l1)
end_out = time.time()